# Macbook 8.1 overheating

Tags: macbook, overheating

I have a macbook 8.1 with ubuntu 12.04 installed. But my cpu is getting very hot.
On Mac my CPU is 50-60°C warm. But on ubuntu my mac is getting very hot and is by about 60°C but with min 3000rpm instead of 2000 on mac and the fan is getting very loud with 4500rpm on ubuntu when im browsing (without flash) or doing something else.
i set it to 3000rpm because it is not getting so noisy instead of 2000rpm minimum.

But thats not that what im expected.

What ive done:

i installed lm-sensors to see the temperatures and started the sensors-detect

i installed macfancld, jupiter, the newest drivers from x-updates and installed the  i965-va-driver

oh and i installed mesa - with the default version my sandbridge was displayed as unknown

i added GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force drm.vblankoffdelay=1 pcie_aspm=force drm.vblankoffdelay=1 i915.semaphores=1 i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 i915.i915_enable_fbc=1"

ive added rfkill block bluetooth to /etc/rc.local to switch of bluetooth by default on boot

my mac is not as noisy as before but it is noisy and sometimes very hot

i hope you can help me

Answer (score 1):

To make this work, I have to boot my mac with efi .

My solution was based on [EFI-Booting Ubuntu on a Mac](http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/index.html).

The writer there says that you have 2 grub files on your efi partition but there should only be one (grubx64.efi) .

The mac is now 5-10°C cooler and the startup is now very short .

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a 13" or 15" Macbook? 15" Macbooks from the past few years come with both a discrete and integrated graphics card. When dual-booting my 15" Macbook 7,2 I had issues of overheating because Ubuntu would use both my discrete and integrated graphics card.  To solve my overheating problem I had to EFI boot (see Timse201's response) and disable my discrete graphics card upon boot, using Grub2. [This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting) provides steps for disabling the discrete graphics card. See [ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook) for more information specific to your Macbook model.

Answer (score 0):

Although these answers, macfanctld etc may be relevant to some people. I realized that the solution for me was that my video card didn't have the proper drivers installed. After installing the AMD specific drivers, my Macbook Pro ran considerably cooler (50%). So if your a newbie to Ubuntu and you have a Macbook Pro with a AMD ATI videocard follow these instructions to install the correct drivers and your computer should run a lot cooler.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

I installed the drivers using the Additional Drivers method.
Additional Drivers can be installed though the Software Center. This made the install pretty much automatic.