# Macbook 8,1 Ubuntu 12.10 CPU Heat

Tags: macbook, cpu, fan, heat

Installed Ubuntu on another partition on my Macbook, which works well sorted the wifi but the problem is that the heat coming off the thing is mental. The fans are going to cool it, and i have installed macfanctl which seems to have helped a little but its still way to hot for idle.

I have managed to boot with EFI yet going to try and sort that but, is that the only factor? Any help with this would be great really want to move from OSX to ubuntu but this will just not work with the heat. I have heard that if i boot with EFI then the graphics switching will work which would be great so im going to try and get that working, but the CPU heat is still a issue.

Thanks

Comment: Possible solution for the same question here! http://askubuntu.com/questions/153647/macbook-8-1-overheating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Merri.

It was related to EFI, now that I am booting from grub-efi, heat and battery performance are much better. The CPU is still slightly warmer than in OSX but not by too much, idles at around 45 - 55 which is quite good for a laptop. If you are having similar problems I would suggest using EFI boot instead of the legacy BIOS.

Here is a post i put on the UBuntu forums on the problem an solution.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2104817

Bill